# QT/QML/C++ media player

Tags: c++, qt, media-player, fast-forward

I have implementeda C++ media player using QT and have variable can access functions like play(), pause() and stop() using QMediaPlayer *player;
So the issue that I am having is that of fastfowarding my player.
I used a comboBox and a Slider to play the video on fastfoward but having troubles connecting it to the rate at which the video is playing.
Please assist me. I can attach my code for you to see what I have done so far, but I am looking for a function/method etc.. that can make player to fastfoward. thank

Answer (score 0):

`QMediaPlayer::setPlaybackRate(qreal rate)` is what you are looking for.  Set it to 2 for twice as fast, for example.

Comment: @Billal I don't understand the question, `QMediaPlayer` is already implemented...

Comment: @cmannet85, on my header file (dialog.h), I created QMediaPlayer* player;. On my Dialog.cpp I created player = new QMediaPlayer(this), SO WHEN I LETS SAY PLAY MY PLAYER, I HAVE THE FOLLOWING METHOD void Dialog::on_playButton_clicked(){player.play;}, so now I want to know what I implement inside the method that you have given me. e.g  void Dialog::setPlayBackRate(qreal rate){ //what do I put here//}

Comment: And how do I incorporate changRate(qreal rate), qreal playbackRate() const, void setPlayBackRate(float rate). ....I can zip my code and email it to you if you do not mind. Thanks

Comment: @Billal You are asking questions that are beyond your original post. " I am looking for a function/method etc.. that can make player to fastfoward" I have provided that, if you need more help then post new questions - SO is not a forum.